# Add UITableViewCells between 2 UITableviewCells in an UITableView with an animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

Right now I am making an iPad app that involves a `UITableView` that involves `UITableView Cells` that slide left and right, I have a `NSNotification` based system of letting the `UITableViewController` know when a slide occurs. I need to display a `UITableViewCell` under the cell that was moved and above the cell that was below the moved cell. I would like to do a fold animation as seen in the app clear but without the `pinch gesture`(i.e. automated fold). I have found this library called [MPFoldTransition](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition). However, it doesn't support `UITableView`. I have also looked into the `pinch gesture` in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22174/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-33), however this tutorial doesn't tell me how to automatically animate the animation, as it requires the users to do a pinch gesture. I have looked around the web and cant seem to find anything. I will appreciate any help whatsoever.

Thanks

Comment: _"however this tutorial uses a UITableViewCell subclass and I cant have that"_ Any particular reason for that?

Comment: The reason is that I need to destroy the UIView immediately (i.e. reanimate it out)

Comment: @ACB I guess I Can theoretiaclly use a very customized UITableViewCell, im sorry for this oversight, I have edited my question to reflect this change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is completely possible using `MPFoldTransition`'s  `transitionFromView: toView:...`. I've created a sample project that I can link to if you'd like, but it all really boils down to this:

```
- (void)addNewTableCellToIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Add the new object to the datasource and reload the row
    [dataSourceArray insertObject:@"New" atIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    //setup temporary cell
    UITableViewCell *fromCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    [fromCell setBackgroundColor:[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] backgroundColor]];
    //setup cell to animate to
    UITableViewCell *toCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [toCell.textLabel setText:dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]];

    //add fold animation to the cells create above
    [MPFoldTransition transitionFromView:fromCell
                                  toView:toCell
                                duration:0.4
                                   style:MPFoldStyleUnfold
                        transitionAction:MPTransitionActionNone
                              completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                              }];
}
```

About is a function that takes the index path as an argument. Send it the index path that you wish to add the cell with a fold transition, and it will create a blank temporary cell on the table to fold from, while shifting the rest of the cells down. It isn't perfect, mostly because I haven't figured out a way to change `UITableViewRowAnimation`'s duration to *perfectly* match up with the folds duration.

Either way, this should be enough to get you going. Hope this helps!